# Shell script to move files in while loop with counter

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to move some files down a directory and rename them

the current file struct looks something like the following:

```
photos ->
  {
    1 -> Auction_Images -> <several image files>
         item_image-1-1.jpg
         item_image-2-1.jpg
         ...
    2 -> Auction_Images -> <several image files>
         item_image-3-1.jpg
         ...
    3 -> Auction_Images -> <several image files> 
    my_script.sh  
  }
```

I want to be able to go into each numbered directory, check how many files/folders exist, if there is only one meaning the Auction_Images dir like folder 3 then I want to go into that Auction_Images dir and moved the photos out one directory and rename them. So far I have the following:

```
x=1
while [ $x -le 3 ]
do
  cd $PWD/$x
  echo Changed to dir: $PWD
  count=ls | wc -l
  echo $count
  if [[ "$count" -eq 1 ]]
  then
    echo $PWD has 1 file/folder
  fi
  echo --------------------------------------------------
  cd ..
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

the output I am getting is:

```
Changed to dir: /Users/jarvis/Desktop/imports/company/photos/1
       0

--------------------------------------------------
Changed to dir: /Users/jarvis/Desktop/imports/company/photos/2
       0

--------------------------------------------------
Changed to dir: /Users/jarvis/Desktop/imports/company/photos/3
       0
```

The expected output would be:

```
Changed to dir: /Users/jarvis/Desktop/imports/company/photos/1
       2

--------------------------------------------------
Changed to dir: /Users/jarvis/Desktop/imports/company/photos/2
       1

--------------------------------------------------
Changed to dir: /Users/jarvis/Desktop/imports/company/photos/3
       0
```

The current problem I am having is that the `count` doesn't seem to be captured correctly.

Comment: `count=ls | wc -l` is an offending instruction. The command substitution syntax is `$(..)`. So use `count=$(ls | wc -l)` and parsing output is not a good design approch

Comment: @Inian thanks. I appreciate the help. this is the first shell script I have written, so I'm still learning.

Comment: `ls` [isn't an appropriate tool to use for purposes other than displaying names for human consumption](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). To count number of files in a directory, see [BashFAQ #4](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004).

Comment: BTW, in the future, please try ask a more focused question -- ie. instead of asking about your script as a whole, asking a part about the one piece of it that doesn't work. See the docs on building a [mcve], describing how a code sample in a question should be the smallest possible thing that demonstrates a given issue.

Comment: It's also worth making a habit of fixing problems identified by http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: ...among other things, expansions should always be quoted, and the exit status of `cd` should be checked to make sure it was successful (otherwise you can be renaming contents of the wrong directory!). `cd -- "$x" || continue`, for example, will skip to the next loop entry if a `cd` fails.

Comment: re: quoting, by the way -- that even applies to safe use of `echo`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). `echo "$PWD has 1 file/folder"` is going to be much better-behaved than the original code if run in a directory that, say, has a whitespace-surrounded `*` in its name.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you could use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

for dir in +([0-9])/; do

    files=("$dir/"*)
    count=${#files[@]}  

    echo "$PWD/$dir"
    echo "$count"

    if (( count == 1 )); then
        #do something
        echo "Only one file/folder"
        mv -- "$files" /some/path/newname
    fi  

    echo "=============================="
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` = ensures you will not execute the loop if there are no directories
- `shopt -s extglob` = enables [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)
- `for dir in +([0-9])/` = loops **only** over directories consisted of one or more numbers
- `files=("$dir/"*)` = stores all files in currently searched directory into an array
- `count=${#files[@]}` = counts the number of elements in the array -- number of files
- `mv -- "$files" /some/path/newname` = moves the first and only element in the `files` array into the new location (note that `$files` is a shorter way of `${files[0]}`)

---

If you don't like the `for` loop I used and you insist on using this:

```
while [ $x -le 3 ]; do
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

you might consider using the [C-style `for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs):

```
for (( x=1; x<=3; x++ )); do
    #do something
done
```

or [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
for x in {1..3}; do
    #do something
done
```

That way you don't have to increment `$x` yourself. On top of that:

1. Quote expansions = `echo "$PWD"`
2. `count=ls | wc -l` = use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) instead: `count=$(ls | wc -l)`
3. [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)